# Adding a omniauth-gem to a omnibus GitLab installation

Tags: ruby, omniauth, gitlab

I am not very experienced with ruby in general and trying to install a new omniauth provider in the GitLab Community Edition. I used the omnibus package to install it on Ubuntu 14.04. The goal is to authenticate GitLab against a Jasig CAS

According to [Custom omniauth provider configurations doc](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Custom-omniauth-provider-configurations) the next step to make this work would be to add the according gem to the gemfile with "gem 'omniauth-cas'".

Is this even possible with the installed omnibus package? Or do I have to install it again manually? I don't see any gemfile in the installation directory, which i suppose to be somewhere down /var/opt/gitlab?

Thank you, everyone!

Comment: Actually, the `Gemfile` is at `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/Gemfile`, but if you run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` will overwrite anything you have changed in that file, so I'm wondering how to do this too.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/821 the official answer is no, only support manual installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the classic installation.

You need to download sources and install Gitlab manually in order to change the Gemfile.

Otherwise like *Leo* said the `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` will override your changes.

This command uses `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` configuration and overrides everything.